# Setting Redhat to mount CDROMs with execute permission automatically

Tags: redhat, mount

When I place a CDROM with some scripts into the drive, Redhat will automatically mount a folder on the desktop. However, I can't execute the scripts on that CD. To do that, I have to manually mount with the 'exec' option. How do I get Redhat to give me 'exec' permission when it auto-mounts the CD?

Answer (score 1):

The procedure for RHEL5 is described at [HAL Tips and Tricks](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/HAL).  I believe that on RHEL4 you just need to adjust /etc/fstab to add "exec" to the mount point, basically what's described there but without so many caveats.

Answer (score 0):

Find this line in /etc/auto.misc:

```
cd              -fstype=iso9660,ro,nosuid,nodev :/dev/cdrom
```

and make it look like this:

```
cd              -fstype=iso9660,ro,nosuid,nodev,exec :/dev/cdrom
```